# How can I get rid of extra monitors on booting screens?

Tags: multiple-monitors, bios

My GPU has had an issue with a 'ghost monitor' since I got it, ie it thinks that there is permanently a monitor plugged into the VGA port despite there not being, I have disabled it in Windows and had no issues for a long time but all of a sudden my BIOS has decided to use this monitor as it's primary, it completely prevents me from using the pc as I have to confirm start-up. Before anyone recommends just using the VGA port, the output has a strong yellow hue and streaks in the image.

Answer (score 0):

The bios is displayed on the highest priority port that is plugged in at boot time.

Generally the port priority is defined in the GPUs firmware by the manufacturer, and is not modifiable by the end user. ([Example documentation from EVGA](https://www.evga.com/support/faq/FAQdetails.aspx?faqid=59560))

Try plugging your monitor into each of the other ports on the GPU while booting up to determine if any of the other ports have higher priority than the VGA port and can trump it during the boot process.